# Spring POST form data sends Â as escape character for special characters not present in the browser request

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-form

I'm using a spring jsp form to send some data back to a controller.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
(...)
<spring:url value="pathA" var="formActionVar"/>
<form:form action="${formActionVar}" modelAttribute="modelA" id="formIdA" method="post">
    <input name="itemA" value="${modelA.itemA}" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input name="itemB" value="${modelA.itemB}" autocomplete="off"/>
    <button id="sendBtn" type="submit">
</form:form>
```

Looking at the browser request, the form data with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded is as follows:

```
itemA=12%C2%A7&itemB=potatoes
```

The problem is that itemA is being converted to 12Â§ (like an escape char to all special chars, §, £, ...) meaning that there is something in between the browser request and the server doing that conversion.

Custom class that extends CharacterEncodingFilter:

```
public class CustomCharEncodingFilter extends CharacterEncodingFilter {

    public CustomCharEncodingFilter() {
        super("UTF-8", true, true);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getCharacterEncoding()); // <-- null
        System.out.println("Encoded param: " + request.getParameter("itemA")); // <-- 12Â§

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");              // <-- tested with these 2 lines but no effect
        setForceEncoding(true);
        
        System.out.println(request.getCharacterEncoding()); // <-- UTF-8

        System.out.println("Encoded param: " + request.getParameter("itemA")); // <-- 12Â§
        super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
    }
}
```

But as you can see the value was already previously converted somewhere disregarding the character encoding.
The weird part is that doing the request using ajax with a parsed form representation does not convert the 12§ value to 12Â§ and the controller gets the correct value.

Edit:
Just a quick note to mention that using enctype="multipart/form-data" in the jsp form changes the itemA value to it's clear form (12§) but still gets the value to be "server-side rendered" as 12Â§

Comment: Use a `form:input` with the proper field declaration instead of a plain `input` element.

Comment: does not work. Already tried it. the browser sends the proper value as I mentioned. itemA=12%C2%A7

Comment: Your filter doesn't make anything work or sense. If it isn't showing the correct encoding you are reading it **before** the filter has any chance of setting the proper encoding. Are you writing stuff to logfiles for instance?

Comment: Logging to console as mentioned above

Comment: `12A§` url encoded (to UTF-8)  is `12A%C2%A7`

Comment: You mean 12%C2%A7 right? (without the first A)

Comment: No, literally... https://amp.urlencoder.org/

Comment: @xerx593 you are right. (still the input I mentioned had no A§ so that wouldn't be the issue I guess) But still the problem lies in the § to %C2%A7

Comment: @M.Deinum did not understand the "Are you writing stuff to logfiles for instance?" question. Could that influence the encoding somehow?